# Claim tax relief on purchase in UK as full time employee

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-deduction, employment

As a full time employee in an I.T. company can I claim tax relief on purchases related to my job?

My employer does not provide a laptop so I was considering buying one myself and was wondering if this was tax deductible via form [P87](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/incometax/how-to-get.htm).

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine it boils down to "can you do your job without a laptop?". If you can then its not a necessary business expense. If you can't then I would suspect it is allowable but I'm wondering why you employer doesn't provide it...

Comment: An alternative would be to ask your employer to set up a salary sacrifice PC purchase scheme, that way you get some tax benefit. [Edited to add example scheme: http://www.computingscheme.co.uk/ ]